# Cassandra connect to cluster if keyspace does not exists

Tags: java, cassandra

I have a problem with connect to cassandra when keyspace does not exists.
I don't want to hardcode my keyspace in application. I want to write keyspace name in application.yml (I am using spring boot). I want to create session with association with keyspace:

```
session = cluster.connect("keyspace");
```

I have to do that because i can't Autowired properties in @Accessor interface.

```
@Accessor
public interface PropertyAccessor {

    //cannot autowire this field
    @Value("${database.keyspace}")
    String keyspace = "";
```

So my question is:

1. How to connect to cassandra cluster and get session object association with keyspace when keyspace does not exists?
2. How to autowire property from spring properties in @Accessor interface?

PS. I am using casandra 3.7 so i can't  use spring-data-cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

If you created, for example, your CustomAccessorRepository annotated with @Accessor

```
@Accessor
public interface CustomAccessorRepository {
   @Query("select from custom where id=':id')
   CustomObject findById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

You could just create some class and annotate it with @Configuration, in this class create a @Bean that returns your accessor

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig {

    private Cluster cluster;

    private Session session;

    private MappingManager mappingManager;

    @Value("${database.keyspace}")
    private String keyspace;

    public CassandraConfig(){
       cluster = Cluster.builder()
             .addContactPoints(nodes.split(","))
             .withPort(port)
             .build();
       session = cluster.connect(keyspace)
       mappingManager = new MappingManager(session);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAccessorRepository customAccessorRepository(){
        return mappingManager.createAccessor(CustomAccessorRepository.class);
    }
}
```

After this you could inject your Accessor to some service

```
@Autowired
private CustomAccessorRepository customAccessorRepository;
```

Comment: The statement _You can't create session without keyspace._ is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, yes i was wrong, actually there is possibility to create session without keyspace but i think this is a bad approach

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: It is complex question and i could be wrong but in this case you have to always specify keyspace in queries it could lead to some mistakes, of course if you have a lot of keyspaces in one service it will be good solution to use one session, but using many keyspaces specially with duplicated tables could lead to performance issues, and i'm not sure is this service well designed in this case.